Read a slice of bytes &[u8] bit by bit
I'm writing a program for hiding data in PNG files. The problem I have is reading data in the form of &[u8] (or Vec<u8>) bit by bit.

struct Data {
    bytes: Vec<u8>,
    index: usize,
}

impl Data {
    fn read_bits(&mut self, n: usize) -> u8 {
        // this function is the issue I don't know how to
        // do this I want this function to read n bits from 
        // self.bytes and return them.
        // if the current read byte is 0b11001011 and n = 2
        // the function should return 0b11 as u8 and update
        // self.index to make sure the next read returns
        // 0b10 aka the next 2 bits from 0b11001011
    }
}

The reason why I need the data in this form is I want to replace the least-significant bits of the color values in a png with the bits from a Vec<u8>
let mut red = ...; // the red channel from a pixel
red = red & 0b11111100; // remove the last 2 bits
red = red + data.read_bits(2); // read two bits from data and add it to the red channel


Hi. Please provide a minimal reproducible example. Remember to specify types of the variables you show, and if you use any libraries, please specify exactly what they are. rust tag has section how to provide MRE for rust code specifically.

Are you trying to implement read_bits() and are stuck, or do you have an issue with a read_bits() provided by a third-party crate (this one comes to mind)? If it's the former, could you edit the question to include your existing implementation, and a more detailed description of how it falls short of your goals? In particular, it's not clear to me what you mean by "get the hidden data back" and "reverse this process".

I'm sorry for causing confusion with the data hiding stuff, I've rewritten the question to be more accurate the the issue I'm having. I dont have an issue with a 3rd party library, I'm having trouble with implementing the read_bits function

Where exactly did you get stuck? The algorithm is simple: keep track of the bit index, get the byte index (bit % 8), using bit twiddling get the correct bits, possibly merging from the next byte too.

The merge with the next byte was the main issue: when extracting 3 bits from a byte with only 2 bit remaining

The bitvec crate allows you to do this.

If n > 8, then read_bits is not going to fit the return value in an u8.

Probably not the most performant but should be what you need.
struct BitIter<'a> {
    data: &'a [u8],
    index: usize
}

impl<'a> BitIter<'a> {
    fn next_n(&mut self, n: usize) -> u8 {
        let mut bits = 0;
        for i in 0..n {
            let bit = self.next().unwrap();
            bits |= bit << i;
        }
        bits
    }
}

impl<'a> Iterator for BitIter<'a> {
    type Item = u8;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<u8> {
        if self.index < self.data.len() * 8 {
            let bit = (self.data[self.index / 8] >> (self.index % 8)) & 1;
            self.index += 1;
            Some(bit)
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
